# Trying to center text on homepage using display: flex when using a header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the text on a web page to centre right in the middle using display: flex whilst I have inserted a header with a logo inside it. I have successfully managed to do so using the following code:

**Method 1**

```
position: absolute
top: 50%
left: 50%
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

The outcome of this is the following: https://codepen.io/pen/QWKrrNq

However, when I try to achieve this with display: flex using the following code:

**Method 2**

```
height: 100%    
display: flex
justify-content: center
align-items: center
flex-direction: column
```

The outcome is the following: https://codepen.io/pen/wvzjjMJ

As you can see with method 1, the text is perfectly centered whereas with method 2, it is not.

I know the reason for this is because of the height that is took up by the header, this has an impact on the space used by the div of the text being centered. However, I would just like to know if it's possible to achieve whats being done in method 1 via display flex?

I have tried changing the height of the text container div from 100% to 80%, 70%, etc... and this seems to work initially however when the viewport width is changed the text becomes off-centered unlike method 1. The only thing I could think of to avoid this is using media queries for different height %'s.

Is there any other simpler way to do this using display: flex?

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

By using flex you can make center by the following code

```
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
margin-top: 50px;
```

Remove the justify-content center and add margin top or padding top to the div

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to handle this would be to just use absolute positioning for the header__nav element, similar to your first example. The header__text element will no longer position itself relative to the nav, and the nav will stay fixed to the top of the page (presumably where you want it)

In your second example, adding the positioning rule:

```
    &__nav
        display: flex
        padding: 1rem
        position: absolute
```

centered the header text for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not perfectly centered is because `header__nav` is taking up the space. And pushes stuff down.

You have to wonder what you want. Can the nav be on top always, like with position: absolute? If that would be no problem. The code below works and centers the title.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: "Andika New Basic", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  height: 95vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #7cc071c0, #168042a2), url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
}
.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.header__nav--logo {
  max-width: 15%;
}
.header__text {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header__text--title {
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.header__text--copy {
  letter-spacing: 0.3rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header__nav">
                <img class="header__nav--logo" src="https://github.com/jonasschmedtmann/advanced-css-course/blob/master/Natours/starter/img/logo-white.png">
            </div>
            <div class="header__text">
                <h1 class="header__text--title">
                    Welcome to my website
                </h1>
                <h2 class="header__text--copy">
                    Click the buttons below to enter
                </h2>
            </div>
        </header>
    </section>
</body>
```